# Given an integer "n", return an array of size "n" that contains the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ...?

Tags: java

My code so far:

```
public int[] arrayCreation1(int n) {
int[] a = new int[0];{}
int i = 0;
for (int i = 0) i<size.length) i++); {

}

return i;

}
```

How would I go about completing this?

Comment: Your for loop is invalid, along with the array initialization. You also redeclare `i`.

Comment: I think the second line should be `int[] a = new int[n];` because an array with zero elements isn't very useful.  Also, you might want to look in the online Java tutorial and see if you can find out the correct syntax for a `for` loop.

Comment: Could you help me out?

Comment: Well, I've given you two suggestions.  Between my comment and your comment, I don't think you spent enough time to have tried them both.

Comment: Try `IntStream.range(0, n).toArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

- the variable i is defined twice. If the variable "i" is for the for loop, you can initialise the variable in the loop itself just like you did "int i = 0".
- the question stated that you are trying to fill in array with integers starting from 0 to n. You have accept a console input or hard code the value n.
- Look up array initialisation and how to assign values.

I think this should get you started atleast.

I am new to programming too and this is what I felt was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have stated, your code has many issues:

- You are defining a as an array of length 0
- You define i as 0 twice
- Your for loop is malformed
- You have a semicolon after your for loop, which is seen as an empty stament and will prevent the loop from iterating over the block.
- Size is not defined anywhere
- You return i, which is an int not an array

Here's some code that will work, but I suggest you spend some time with a book or tutorial:

```
public int[] createArray(int n){
    int[] out = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        out[i] = i;
    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: You need to determine how the numbers correlate to the index of the array.  In your example, there appears to be an offset of 10 + the index * 2.  So a change to "out[i] = 10 + i * 2;" would do it.

Comment: Appreciate  the help

Comment: How do I return an array but with the first and last elements swapped

Comment: This feels like a homework question.  If you have a lesson ahead of these questions, I recommend that you reread it.  Consider which elements you want to swap and how you would reference them.